# Cannot convert value of type 'CFTimeInterval.Type' to 'CFTimeInterval'?

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm going over a programming example in a book on Swift and have an initializer to an SKScene that looks like this:

```
class GameOverScene: SKScene
{
    init(size:CGSize,won:Bool,time:CFTimeInterval)
    {
       ...........
    }
}
```

This initializer is then called in another part of the program with the following line:

```
let gameOverScene=GameOverScene(size:self.size,won:true,time:CFTimeInterval)
```

It seems that this should all be fairly simple but then I get this strange looking error that says:

> Cannot convert value of type 'CFTimeInterval.Type (aka 'Double.Type')
>   to expected argument type 'CFTimeInterval' (aka 'Double').

Does anyone know (1) what this error means and (2) how to correct it?

Comment: What is the `time` parameter in this initializer supposed to mean?

Comment: @Alexander - the 'time' parameter is simply a CFTimeInterval variable which describes the amount of time that the game has taken when the game has ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFTimeInterval` is a type. It's not an instance of `CFTimeInterval` that you can pass into that function.

`CFTimeInterval` is a `typealias` to `Double`. So this function expects a value of type `Double`. `1.0`, `NaN`, `-1.5`, `Double.pi` are all valid instances of `Double`. But what you're trying to give it is `CFTimeInterval`, which refers to the type itself.

This, for example, would work:

```
let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: true, time: 1.23)
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel like an idiot. I was trying to pass the 'CFTimeInterval' type itself as an argument rather than realizing that what was called for was an item which was a 'CFTimeInterval' type. I was confusing the syntax used for declaring an init with the syntax used for calling the init.

Comment: No worries. But please, put some spaces in your code. Orelseitalljustreadslikethis,andit'snotverypleasanttoworkwith.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Btw, are you using some old version of Swift? Modern Swift gives you an error in such a case, reminding you to either use `CFTimeInterval()` to call some initializer, or use explicitly write `CFTimeInterval.self` to refer to the type.

Comment: I try to keep Xcode and Swift always updated to the latest version, but I'll check that. Thanks.